unable to start node project or install node
my node was working earlier but now it appears it not working anymore.
i create a new project and realize the issue is not within my code, but the actual node itself.
chatgpt is insiting is something to do with the verions of brew/node but im not sure thats the problem.
below is the inputs/outputs i tried but didnt get any luck.
(base) juan@192 server % npm init
dyld[19491]: Library not loaded: /opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib
  Referenced from: <E52D9D5D-9957-386D-9594-32159BF15B1A> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@14/14.21.3_1/libexec/node
  Reason: tried: '/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/74.2/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/74.2/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/74.2/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
zsh: abort      npm init
(base) juan@192 server % 

i tried to uninstall/install node but that didnt work.
i tried updating brew but that didnt work.
i tried installing icu4c but that didnt work and i see an error::
(base) juan@192 server % brew reinstall icu4c

==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/icu4c/manifests/74.2
Already downloaded: /Users/juan/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/3e5230e726e5548db28bc0cf75710d6405903b742f941113d3dbe7483fad72a4--icu4c-74.2.bottle_manifest.json
==> Fetching icu4c
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/icu4c/blobs/sha256:3facc22a7821e01d93a38e371e377f13275299d518929222ed34c77a4f4a65d3
Already downloaded: /Users/juan/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/ce50ca66b48d7c7f36ee7ec0a644bbeaf961faf2b4f333992d9e85c8e051a981--icu4c--74.2.arm64_sonoma.bottle.tar.gz
==> Reinstalling icu4c 
==> Pouring icu4c--74.2.arm64_sonoma.bottle.tar.gz
  /opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/74.2: 270 files, 77.9MB
==> Running `brew cleanup icu4c`...
Disable this behaviour by setting HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_CLEANUP.
Hide these hints with HOMEBREW_NO_ENV_HINTS (see `man brew`).
==> No outdated dependents to upgrade!
==> Checking for dependents of upgraded formulae...
Disable this behaviour by setting HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALLED_DEPENDENTS_CHECK.
Hide these hints with HOMEBREW_NO_ENV_HINTS (see `man brew`).
==> Reinstalling 1 dependent with broken linkage from source:
node@14
Error: node@14 has been disabled because it is not supported upstream!
(base) juan@192 server % 

i cant seem to check the node version for some reason::
(base) juan@192 server % node --version
dyld[21510]: Library not loaded: /opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib
  Referenced from: <E52D9D5D-9957-386D-9594-32159BF15B1A> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@14/14.21.3_1/libexec/node
  Reason: tried: '/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/74.2/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/74.2/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/74.2/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)

i can check icu verions::
icuinfo --versio
error in command line argument "--versio"
 <icuSystemParams type="icu4c">
    <param name="copyright"> Copyright (C) 2016 and later: Unicode, Inc. and others. License & terms of use: http://www.unicode.org/copyright.html </param>
    <param name="product">icu4c</param>
    <param name="product.full">International Components for Unicode for C/C++</param>
    <param name="version">74.2</param>
    <param name="version.unicode">15.1</param>
    <param name="platform.number">3500</param>
    <param name="platform.type">Darwin</param>
    <param name="locale.default">en_US</param>
    <param name="locale.default.bcp47">en-US</param>
    <param name="converter.default">UTF-8</param>
    <param name="icudata.name">icudt74l</param>
    <param name="icudata.path"></param>
    <param name="cldr.version">44.1</param>
    <param name="tz.version">2023c</param>
    <param name="tz.default">America/Bogota</param>
    <param name="cpu.bits">64</param>
    <param name="cpu.big_endian">0</param>
    <param name="os.wchar_width">4</param>
    <param name="os.charset_family">0</param>
    <param name="os.host">arm-apple-darwin23.2.0</param>
    <param name="build.build">arm-apple-darwin23.2.0</param>
    <param name="build.cc">clang</param>
    <param name="build.cxx">clang++</param>
    <param name="uconfig.internal_digitlist">1</param>
    <param name="uconfig.have_parseallinput">1</param>
 </icuSystemParams>


ICU Initialization returned: U_ZERO_ERROR
Plugins are disabled.

even if i uninstall/install node it does not appear to work::
(base) juan@192 server % brew reinstall node   
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/node/manifests/22.0.0
Already downloaded: /Users/juan/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/2de85ef19cd0ba7bdc9cfe6be3c2faf096feb1ece0319ca6539cfbfacbda46c1--node-22.0.0.bottle_manifest.json
==> Fetching node
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/node/blobs/sha256:951f45bf577ecbaf4bb5f0184a112a85c3cd155961f00a7885b49e0195b77749
Already downloaded: /Users/juan/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/df497e7a8a284af05244be6911b45cc05b6e0b46183ec85e96d200942c010193--node--22.0.0.arm64_sonoma.bottle.tar.gz
==> Reinstalling node 
==> Pouring node--22.0.0.arm64_sonoma.bottle.tar.gz
  /opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/22.0.0: 2,140 files, 75.6MB
==> Running `brew cleanup node`...
Disable this behaviour by setting HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_CLEANUP.
Hide these hints with HOMEBREW_NO_ENV_HINTS (see `man brew`).
(base) juan@192 server % node --version

dyld[23390]: Library not loaded: /opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib
  Referenced from: <E52D9D5D-9957-386D-9594-32159BF15B1A> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@14/14.21.3_1/libexec/node
  Reason: tried: '/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/74.2/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/74.2/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/74.2/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
zsh: abort      node --version
(base) juan@192 server % 

the expected result is that npm init works.
this stackoverflow seems to be related but none of its solutions work on my machine.
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.62.dylib error running php after installing node with brew on Mac
this is all the code i have so far::


Try uninstalling node via brew and making sure to remove any traces of it leftover from that. Then install a Node version manager like NVM, Volta, etc. Common for Brew to screw up Node in random stupid ways, and it's easier to avoid Brew (at least for Node; I avoided it in general instead after multiple instances of non-Node issues, while I had a Mac).
